# Enable Button Clickable after writing certain text in textview android

Tags: android

I am trying to build a Sign in method in which one person has to write its Email Address of the particular domain 
e.g `rob@playground.football.in`

Now my intention my codes should check the domain i.e playground.football.in then if it matches then only the button which is for signing in(which is disable/unclickable before writing the particular domain) should be enabled now.

I have done half of the work.for getting the domain shown below

```
email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email); verify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); verify.setEnabled(false); String getEmail = email.getText().toString();
String x = getEmail.substring(getEmail.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
if (x.equals(domain)) {
verify.setEnabled(true); 
}
```

Comment: email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        verify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        verify.setEnabled(false);
        String getEmail = email.getText().toString();
        String x = getEmail.substring(getEmail.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);
        if (x.equals(domain))
        {
         verify.setEnabled(true);

        }

Comment: so what's the problem exactly?

Comment: See my answer below. hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `TextChangedListener` to your email `EditText` using `email.addTextChangedListener()` and put your checking inside `onTextChanged()`.

**Here is the working code. Update your code as below:**

```
    ..................
    .........................
    EditText email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    Button verify = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    verify.setEnabled(false);

    email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            String getEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String x = getEmail.substring(getEmail.lastIndexOf('@') + 1);

            if (x.equals(domain)) { 
                verify.setEnabled(true); 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });
    ..............
    .....................
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: @Rob If my solution works perfectly then mark this answer as accepted. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Sorry bro actually my net was stucked and i couldn't say thankyou properly.. your codes really is awesome. it helped me in very fabolus way  after editing some pieces on your code. @Ferdous Ahamed

Comment: can i get your facebook email id please... @Ferdous Ahamed